# Using timestamp function in Postgres SQL while inserting json data

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to insert timestamp into json data into a column called 'conversations' of type "jsonb"

this is what I want the data to look like-

```
{
"sender": "John",
"message": "Issue",
"msgAt": "2022-11-11"}
```

Below is my attempt at the above,which is not the correct format for the function NOW()

```
    INSERT INTO ticket_data(conversations) VALUES('{"sender":"John","message":"Issue","msgAt":NOW()}');
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

From [JSON functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) *Table 9.47. JSON Creation Functions*.

```
select json_build_object('sender', 'John', 'message', 'Issue', 'msgAt', current_date);
                        json_build_object                         
------------------------------------------------------------------
 {"sender" : "John", "message" : "Issue", "msgAt" : "2022-10-23"}
```

Changed `now()` to `current_date` as that was what you wanted to end up with.

Answer (score 0):

```
select ('{"sender":"John","message":"Issue",' || '"msgAt":'|| '"' || ( now()::date) ||'"' ||'}')::json;
```

or use parameter.

```
DO $$
DECLARE
    _date date;
BEGIN
    _date := now();
    RAISE NOTICE '%', json_build_object('sender', 'John', 'message', 'Issue', 'msgAt', _date);
END
$$;
```